# How can I select a field and nested array from a JSON using JSONPath?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

From the contacts, I'd like to select the values in fields: "Id" (47) and everything from the nested array [doNotContact]. I could use some help defining the JSONPath-filter I should be using to select the values: 47 and each value inside the nested array.

```
{
    "total": "1",
    "contacts": {
        "47": {
            "id": 47,
            "isPublished": true,
            "dateAdded": "2015-07-21T12:27:12-05:00",
            "createdBy": 1,
            "createdByUser": "Joe Smith",
            "doNotContact": [{
                "id": 2,
                "reason": 2,
                "comments": "",
                "channel": "email",
                "channelId": null
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried paths like: $.contacts.*.['id','doNotContact'] however, this does not seem to work. I am using the website: https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ normally this would help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not all implementations support the comma-delimited selectors, e.g. `['id','doNotContact']`.  See the [JSON Path comparison project site](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/) (specifically [this test](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/results/union_with_keys.html)) for information as to which implementations support the syntax.

Secondly, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74424360/878701) about omitting the dot before a bracket syntax